# Query 1 ERROR: Unknown column in 'field list' but the column in known

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-8.0

MYSQL 8 - New to sql so please go easy on me! Trying to show percentage difference between two different columns but it gives me this error even though the column does exist.

please see my sql query below thanks in advance

```
SELECT
    New_application_request_2021.week_id AS week_id,
    New_application_request_2020.week_commencing_date AS week_commencing_date_2020,
    New_application_request_2021.week_commencing_date AS week_commencing_date_2021,
    (New_application_request_2021.application_request) - (New_application_request_2020.application_request) / ((New_application_request_2020.application_request) * 100) AS percentage_difference
FROM
    New_application_request_2021

    FULL JOIN New_application_request_2020 ON New_application_request_2021.week_id = New_application_request_2020.week_id
GROUP BY
    week_commencing_date_2021;
```

Comment: MySQL does not support `full join`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  I logged a bug about this in 2013: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69858

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not support full joins.  So, your from clause is being interpreted as:

```
FROM New_application_request_2021 full JOIN
----------------------------------^ table alias
     New_application_request_2020
     ON New_application_request_2021.week_id = New_application_request_2020.week_id
```

Your qualified column names don't work, because they are not using `full`.

You might want to ask a *new* question with sample data and desired results for alternative methods of getting what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure why you are using Group by clause. But if it is mandatory to use then you have 2 options to resolve the issue. 1. use all the columns in the select in group by. 2. use aggregate functions such as Min, Max for the columns which are not in the group by.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).